# Recommendation Letter: How to properly mention the grade and the rank of a student in multiple courses?

Tags: masters, recommendation-letter, ranking

I am writing a letter of recommendation for my student as he is applying for a master's degree to study in the UK. The GUIDANCE FOR REFEREES states that I should mention the grades of the applicant in the courses I taught him, as well as his rank in each one in comparison with other students (i.e., with how many students am I comparing the applicant?). If fact, I taught him five courses, and I need **an example** of how to properly state the required information without repeating the same sentence multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> X attended with me class A (grade A), class B (grade B), [...] and class
> E (grade E).

Or your preferred variation of the above. However, you can also repeat the grade statement several times, possibly adding for each class details about the student's participation.

Comment: What about his rank in comparison with x students in each class?

Comment: @catfour Within the parentheses as well.

Comment: @catfour class A (grade A, rank/total), etc etc? I think you're overcomplicating this.

Comment: Honestly, I was not sure if, e.g., Statistics (92%, 2nd/31) is the formal/conventional way to write such details. Also, do you think it is a good idea to mention such details to any other university/scholarship who may ask me to submit a letter of recommendation about an outstanding student, even if they did not ask for such details (especially the rank in each course)? Thank you.

Comment: Given that most places will also have transcripts for the student, it seems to be redundant generally. I'd only provide the information if asked.

Comment: @Buffy I agree that it's redundant, but the OP says "GUIDANCE FOR REFEREES states that I should mention the grades of the applicant in the courses I taught him".