# Recommendation Letter: the final position of a student in the class

Tags: recommendation-letter, formatting, ranking

Suppose there are 25 students in a class, where two students scored 100/100, and **four students scored 96/100**, while the rest of the students scored below that. The question is: Should I mention the position of a student who scored 96/100 as "3rd out of 25 students", or is there a more appropriate way?

Comment: Well, no matter what, it's certainly not 2nd, since two students were ahead of this student! I would probably write "this student and three others had the same result, the 3rd through 6th best in the class." I'm surprised to see so many ties, though.

Comment: @KevinArlin Sorry for the typo. In the case of multiple courses,  It may seem redundant to write all these words for each one. Could you please write your answer to [such a case](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/154970/129224).

Comment: You could just write "3/25", but it would be a bit more informative to write "tied for 3/25". I don't really see any of these options as being importantly different from each other, either for the effect of the letter or for its length.

Comment: @KevinArlin You can however say the student got the 2nd highest score on the exam.

Answer (score 2):

The student was "tied for third" place out of 25. That would be the common way to express it in the US (and in most sports). The same would be true if everyone else in the class (but the two top) had 96 also.

Comment: Thank you for these details. Could you please edit your answer to give an example for a case of multiple courses (see [my previous question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/154972/129224)), in some of them, say two, the student has the same condition mentioned in this question. I want to write in a correct and formal style.

Comment: I wonder if most places need that sort of detail. If so, they will probably ask for it, but speaking in superlatives generally is possibly enough. "At or near the top of the class in several courses". The institution will most likely see official transcripts.

Comment: Some scholarships/universities asked for such details (e.g.,  Saïd Foundation Scholarship: [Referee guide](https://www.saidfoundation.org/pages/14-references)). Hence, I think it is a good idea to generalize these informative details in all letters of recommendation.

Comment: Kindly write an example for such a case.

Comment: And what do you mean by "but the two top"? Isn't it correct to say, e.g., statistics (100%, tied for first place out of 25)?